# angular position fix inside a controller (angular modal?)

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

This is sort of a weird problem that is a mix of css and angular.

I have a div item that is in the main content area of my app that has a few smaller div containers in side of it. Basically,  inside of one of these sub divs I want to be able to click something and have a modal come up and position fix until it's closed.

The problem I am having is that is I would have to put something in the body to fix it to float in the center of the screen, and I feel like I only have control over items (within the controller in the sub div container). So if this were just jquery/javascript I would just append a modal to the body with position fixed. My questions is how to deal with this in angular in this scenario? How can i control a modal that I would normally have to append to a body to get the correct position fixed effect from inside a controller that's tucked into a bunch of divs.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at the Angular UI Bootstrap?  They have a modal component there:

http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Comment: I am using foundation for this project unfortunately :(

Comment: No worries, there's modals for Foundation too:  http://pineconellc.github.io/angular-foundation/